# what's a good/structured way to prevent memcached CacheKeyWarning's?

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I was wondering if anyone knew of a handy way or method to make sure the keys you pass to `django.core.cache.set()` or `cache.get()` are ok.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/#cache-key-warnings:

> Memcached, the most commonly-used production cache backend, does not
>   allow  cache keys longer than 250 characters or containing whitespace
>   or control characters, and using such keys will cause an exception.

I found this `md5_constructor()` function here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/hashcompat.py,

maybe one way is to md5-ifiy the key you use always?   Not 100% sure if that's safe or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to use a custom key function https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHES-KEY_FUNCTION

Set it in your settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'KEY_FUNCTION': 'path.to.my.make_key',
        'LOCATION': [
            '127.0.0.1:11211',
        ]
    }
}
```

I would use something like:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

def _smart_key(key):
    return smart_str(''.join([c for c in key if ord(c) > 32 and ord(c) != 127]))

def make_key(key, key_prefix, version):
    "Truncate all keys to 250 or less and remove control characters"
    return ':'.join([key_prefix, str(version), _smart_key(key)])[:250]
```

Comment: `key` is a dict, not a string. Should be `str(key)`.

Comment: @sikmir nope. `key` is a string.

Answer (score 8):

1. `md5_constructor` is `hashlib.md5` in standard library, its `digest` method can return safe key fit the length limit. If the length of your original key is bigger than 250, you should use it or others to make key safe.
2. for every character in origin key, make sure `ord(character) >= 33`, if not, replace unsafe character with underscore or other safe character you like.